# How to hide a django field in a form but keep its original widget attributes

Tags: django, forms

I know to hide a django field in a form by a forms.HiddenInput widget:

```
flavor_type = forms.CharField(choices=(('a', _('A'),), ('b', _('B'),)),
                              widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

The field will be hidden from display but still is kept in the form. But at the same time, I need its other attributes like 'class' and 'data-slug':

```
flavor_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices=(('a', _('A'),), ('b', _('B'),)),,
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                                attrs={'class': 'switch_radio',
                                       'data-slug': 'flavor_type'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, because `radio` and `hidden` both a input types

I think `MultipleHiddenInput` is what you are looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#MultipleHiddenInput